# Send binary pdf file with express

Tags: node.js, file, pdf, express, binaryfiles

im using [html-pdf](https://www.npmjs.com/package/html-pdf) package for node and i need to send the file as a response.
this is my actual code on the `pdf.create` function

```
pdf.create(html, options).toStream((err, stream) => {
  if(err) throw err;
  stream.pipe(fs.createWriteStream(__dirname + '/gen.pdf'));


  var file = fs.createReadStream(__dirname + '/gen.pdf');
  //file.pipe(res);

  res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/pdf');
  res.setHeader('Content-Disposition', 'attachment; filename="gen.pdf"');
  res.sendFile(__dirname+'/gen.pdf');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not just stream directly to the response? For example:

```
pdf.create(html, options).toStream((err, stream) => {
  if (err) throw err;
  res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/pdf');
  res.setHeader('Content-Disposition', 'attachment; filename="gen.pdf"');
  stream.pipe(res);
});
```

Comment: i'm testing with **postman** (chrome app) and i get a txt file called _response.pdf.pdf_